# ArcGIS Viewer for Flex - multiple feature services

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer, feature-service

I have two operational feature service layers in the flex viewer config.xml file, when I try to load both layers I get this error:

> Office Locations layer failed to load: Fault code: 500 Fault info: An
>   unexpected error occurred processing the request. Fault details:

Interestingly, I can comment out either of the two layers (leaving only one operation layer), which allows me to edit with no error.  Both layers are coming out of the same SDE database.  Why can I not edit both layers?  My geometry service has a min/max of two instances.  Here is my code.

```
    <geometryservice> url="http://MyServer/arcgis1/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer"</geometryservice>

         <operationallayers>

            <layer label="Office Locations" type="feature" visible="true"
                   url="http://MyServer/arcgis1/rest/services/WICKSflexOffice/FeatureServer/1"/> 
            <layer label="Industrial Parks" type="feature" visible="true"
                   url="http://MyServer/arcgis1/rest/services/WICKSflexIndustrial/FeatureServer/0"/> 

        </operationallayers>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two separate published resources each with one feature class. I combined both feature classes into one published resource, and now I can edit both from the api.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can see to look at is the feature template model.

[editing widget](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#//01m30000000v000000)
Have you set them up in arcmap?
[feature template model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003zm000000.htm)

Comment: I took the default feature template model for each published feature service (both layers are point feature classes).

Comment: hmm? with the same schema maybe? same field names, etc.

Comment: If so you may have to build a switcher of sorts. to make one uneditable/editable.

Comment: I had two separate published resource each with one feature class.  I combined both feature classes into one published resource, and now I can edit both from the api.  Both schemas are similar, except for the values of one field.

Comment: interesting - I am in the process of making the same change.